# Electric field lines and coordinates

Tags: electromagnetism

The cross product between nabla and electric field  equals to zero ($\nabla \times \vec{E}=0$) so that means that the field lines are not curved. The relation that gives as the $\vec{E}$ if we use spherical coordinates includes only the $r$ component. Why does it not include the $\phi$ and $\theta$ coordinates too?

Comment: What you call "cross product between nabla and electric field" is called the curl of the electric field. That's a good term to learn.

Comment: Thank you Bill!!

Comment: I think you should revise your understanding of the consequence of the curl of a vector field being zero. As far as I remember Purcell's textbook on electromagnetism should contain enough material (and pictures) to develop your own qualitative inderstanding about curl and divergence of vector fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electric field $\textbf{E}_{\rm point}$ due to a *point charge* is spherically symmetric i.e. it does *only* depend upon how far you are from that charge. Such force fields are called *[central force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_force)* fields. But the electric field due to a dipole $\textbf{E}_{\rm dip}$ (for example)  will, in general, depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$. But central or not, electrostatic field is always *irrotational* or *conservative* i.e., $\nabla\times\textbf{E}=0$.

A non-rotating vector field may also have a nonzero curl. For instance, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)#Example_2). Also as G. Smith pointed out in his comment below, a curved vector field does not ensure a nonzero curl.

Comment: And the field lines of the dipole are curved despite the fact that the field has no curl.

Comment: Good point! @G.Smith

Comment: The curl doesn't measure curvature - it measures rotation. The link to example where $\nabla \times F \neq 0$ is just not obvious.